# Dis-aggregate data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to dissagregate a data frame based on column values. I guess I am looking at the inverse of the dplyr summarise function or possible unstack ?

Input

```
Person  |   Sales

John    |    2

Peter   |    2
```

Desired output

```
Person  |   Sales

John    |    1

John    |    1

Peter   |    1

Peter   |    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a new `data.frame` by replicating the 'Person' column in the original dataset by the 'Sales' and the 'Sales' column as 1.

```
data.frame(Person=rep(df1$Person, df1$Sales), Sales=1)
```

Or replicate the rows with 'Sales' and `transform` the 'Sales' column.

```
transform(df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), df1$Sales),], Sales=1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Person = c("John", "Peter"), Sales = c(2L, 2L)), 
.Names = c("Person", "Sales"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```